# Commenting flex property does not work inside media-query

Tags: flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a following problem.

I have some code in HTML and CSS for full-width screen. I need to make changes for mobile-device.
I have display: flex property in full-width and my paragraphs stand side by side. Requirement is: to place paragraphs one below another when switching below some width.
In order to achieve this, I commented flex properties inside media-query. However, it does not help, width of paragraphs change, but flex property remains. As a result, paragraphs still stand side-by-side. It seems that media-query inherits display:flex from full-width code and I do not understand why it does so.

```
`<div class="par">                    
<p class="flexpar">Paragraph 1 </p>
<p class="flexpar">Paragraph 2 </p>
</div>`
```

```
`.par {
width: 983px;
height: 194px;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
column-gap: 84px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
```

}

```
.flexpar {
    width: 50%;
    
}`
```

```
 `@media (max-width: 768px) {




.par {
    width: 445px;
    height: 194px;
    /* display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 84px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    

}
 
/*.flexpar {
    width: 50%;
    
} */
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Because commenting code just do nothing

If you want to revert the display flex property for mobile device you can just use `display:block` inside your media query

```css
.par {
  display:flex;
  height: 194px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 84px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.flexpar {
    width: 50%;   
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .par {
    display:block
  }
  .flexpar {
      width: 100%;   
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="par">                    
<p class="flexpar">Paragraph 1 </p>
<p class="flexpar">Paragraph 2 </p>
</div>
```

A better solution may be to use mobile fist approach (define first your mobile behaviour and desktop inside the media query)

```css
.column {
 background: pink
}
.column:nth-child(odd){
 background: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .row{
    display: flex;
  }
  .column {
    width: 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 2
  </div>
</div>
```